# capturing inner matches #2 and #4 and replace them

Tags: regex

I have a simple [regex](http://regexr.com/3c2q9): `/((\[#)(\w+)(\]))/g`.

this captures the groups i want to capture. An example group would be `[#recipient]`. I need to capture the opening `[#` and replace with `{{` leave the `\w+` and capture the closing `]` and replace it with `}}` so that this string can be included into a `twig` email template using the string loader extension of twig.

**TLDR**; the goal is to transform: `[#recipient]` `{{recipient}}`, regardless of what the inner word `\w+` might be.

I am not very experienced with regex, and anything more than a basic `preg_match` is beyond my capabilities currently. should i just use `str_replace`? i'm worried about cases where the user forgot to close their statement and using string replace i have no way to ensure that the `\w+` matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex in PHP:

```
$re = '\[#(\w+)\]'; 
$str = "Hello [#recipient] how are you today?\n\nThis email is writing to inform you of [#message]\n\nregards,\n[#from]\n[#website]"; 
$subst = "{{$1}}"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Or else use this regex if you want to allow any text inside `[#...]`:

```
$re = '\[#([^]]+)\]';
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pR3gV2/1)

Comment: only valid variable names could be included inside, so words only. your version works perfect. according to the regex101 site. it passes for all failure cases i need to exclude. thanks!

Comment: they make you wait a certain amount of time before accepting answers now.

Comment: Yes understood, I think they have some kind of wait time. Thanks for your acceptance.